# Unmarshalling nested or complex data elements in JAVA Web services

Tags: java, xml, web-services, arraylist, jaxb

We are developing JAVA web services and have come up with input to the web services. The input has data elements and the last element is an Arraylist which has four items.  We are able to get the values of  first set of elements which are not in arraylist and then save or store them in a database.  The challenge we have is to get the values of nested elements  in arraylist .

We are using the  following code but it is complaining or giving error message that it cannot see (DataInfo.xml) XML file. Which we believe is being generated  by the web services input but we cannot see it.

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(DataInfo.class);
Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();          
DataInfo  EXitems = (DataInfo) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(new File("DataInfo.xml") );
```

How can we ensure that the XML is seen by the code (application) or what is the best way of getting  values  from arraylist or nested elements??

Same code we are using

Main class

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "DataInfo", propOrder = {"firstName","surname", "dateofBirth","studentAddress"})
@XmlRootElement(name = "dataInfo")                                          
public class DataInfo  implements Serializable {

}
```

ArrayList Class

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "studentAddress", propOrder = {"address1","address2", "town","country"})
@XmlRootElement(name = "studentAddress")                                            
public class studentAddress  implements Serializable {

}
```

I have removed getters and setters to shorten the code when posting

Please help

Comment: JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(DataInfo.class);
       Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();          
    DataInfo  EXitems = (DataInfo) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(new File("DataInfo.xml") );  How can I ensure that DataInfo.xml is generated automtaically or at run time?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this worked for me,

```
@XmlElementWrapper(name = "ProfileList")
@XmlElement(name = "Profile")
private List<Profile> listOfProfiles;
```

for an XML structure like,

```
....
<ProfileList>
    <Profile>......</Profile>
    <Profile>......</Profile>
</ProfileList>
....
```