# XStream xml to object with own list implementation

Tags: java, xml, xstream

I have the following XML:

```
<Person>
  <siblings>
    <siblings>
      <Sibling>
        <forename>Bob</forename>
        ...
      </Sibling>
    </sibings>
  </siblings>
</Person>
```

Which I am trying to parse to a Java Object:

```
public class Person() {
  private Siblings siblings;
}

public class Siblings() {
  private MyList<Sibling> siblings;
}

public class Sibling() {
  private String forename;
}
```

The `Siblings` class uses a an implementation of `java.util.List`:

```
public class MyList<E> extends AbstractList<E> 
    implements List<E>, RandomAccess, Cloneable, java.io.Serializable {
  // code
}
```

During the conversion, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: Cannot deserialize object with new readObject()/writeObject() methods
---- Debugging information ----
message             : Cannot deserialize object with new     readObject()/writeObject() methods
class               : utils.xtreamtest.MyList
required-type       : utils.xtreamtest.MyList
converter-type      :     com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.SerializableConverter
path                : /Person/siblings/siblings
line number         : 3
class[1]            : utils.xtreamtest.Siblings
converter-type[1]   :     com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ReflectionConverter
class[2]            : utils.xtreamtest.Person
version             : 1.4.9
-------------------------------
```

I'm guessing this is because xstream doesn't know what the `MyList` class is? Would I do this using an alias and if so, how as there are two levels of `siblings`. I will not be able to edit the source code to add annotations.

Comment: You can give XmlElementWrapper annotations a try for this. [See](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32764083/unmarshalling-nested-or-complex-data-elements-in-java-web-services)

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately I won't be able to edit the source code of the objects to add annotations.

Comment: Wondering if this is something to do with my list implementation class overriding the `readObject()` and `writeObject()` methods? I've tried [this](http://xstream.10960.n7.nabble.com/Disable-SerializableConverter-so-that-Reflection-converts-are-used-td5450.html) but I now get a `UnknownFieldException` for `utils.xtreamtest.MyList.Sibling`.

Comment: Why not use a separate class for XML interchange and define ways to create new instance of your framework class using it ? I know you won't agree to this.

Comment: Yes, the implementation of `readObject()/writeObject()` has to be written in your class, as they are not present in `AbstractList` class. You can see that `LinkedList` & `ArrayList` classes have given implementation to the same.

Comment: My implementation of `ArrayList` does implement `readObject()/writeObject()`. I'm not sure why XStream can't use them?